# STM32 I2C Transfer with DMA completed but DMA interrupt routine is not work

Tags: stm32, interrupt, i2c, dma, hal

I work on basic i2c example with DMA using HAL library. When i observed data in the debug section that data read correctly but DMA did not rise flag TCIF(transfer complete flag). What might be reason ?

```
// INTERRUPT ROUTINE
    void DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler(void) {
    if(__HAL_DMA_GET_FLAG(&hdma_i2c2_rx,DMA_FLAG_TC1)){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_COM_BLUE_GPIO_Port, LED_COM_BLUE_Pin);
    sprintf(prnt, "Id:%.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x\r", Id[7], Id[6],
    Id[5], Id[4], Id[3], Id[2], Id[1], Id[0]);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*) prnt, strlen(prnt), 1000);
    __HAL_DMA_CLEAR_FLAG(&hdma_i2c2_rx,DMA_FLAG_TC1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the HAL, you should let the HAL handle the IRQ and use only the predefined callback.

Look for them in 'stm32fyxx_hal_i2c.h':

```
/******* I2C IRQHandler and Callbacks used in non blocking modes 
(Interrupt and DMA) */
void HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_ER_IRQHandler(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_AddrCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t TransferDirection, uint16_t AddrMatchCode);
void HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_MemTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_MemRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
void HAL_I2C_AbortCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);
```

Be sure to check 'stm32fyxx_it.c' if you don't use CubeMX, you should have something like that :

```
void I2Cx_EV_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(&I2cHandle);
}

/**
  * @brief  This function handles I2C error interrupt request.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  * @Note   This function is redefined in "main.h" and related to I2C error
  */
void I2Cx_ER_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_I2C_ER_IRQHandler(&I2cHandle);
}

/**
  * @brief  This function handles DMA interrupt request.  
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  * @Note   This function is redefined in "main.h" and related to DMA stream 
  *         used for I2C data transmission     
  */
void I2Cx_DMA_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(I2cHandle.hdmarx);
}

/**
  * @brief  This function handles DMA interrupt request.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  * @Note   This function is redefined in "main.h" and related to DMA stream 
  *         used for I2C data reception    
  */
void I2Cx_DMA_TX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(I2cHandle.hdmatx);
}
```

If you don't, check all NVIC options in CubeMX for I2C and DMA, it will create theses lines, and then callbacks functions should works.

If you want to use these "low level" flags, I recommend you to not use the HAL to be sure to have full control over them.

You can also use the LL (low level) library.